# case statement using a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to base the outcome from my code on a date. I want to use a temp table and a case statement, but that does not seem to be working. I am using SQL 2012   thanks

```
if object_id('tempdb..#abc') is not null drop table #abc
 create table #abc (abc varchar(25)
         , codetype varchar (25)
                        )
    Insert into #abc select 253.2, 'abc9'
    Insert into #abc select 428.41, 'abc10'

select pat.id
, edg.CODE
,  case when DATE > '9/1/2014' then abc.codetype = 'abc9' else abc.codetype = 'abc10' end

from pat
left join dx on pat.csn = dx.csn
left join edg on dx.dx = edg.dx
inner join #code9 as abc on abc.abc = edg.CODE 

where
 pat.DATE between '9/2/2014' and '9/2/2014'
```

Comment: `that does not seem to be working` -- what does "not working" mean... it throws an error, does nothing, erupts into flames, what?

Comment: your select doesn't use the temptable #abc at all

Comment: You are filtering on rows where `DATE` is always 9/2/2014, yet your case statement checks if the date is > 9/1/2014 or not.  Isn't 9/2/2014 **always** greater than 9/1/2014?

Comment: You are updating a column within a SELECT CASE statement?  That does not make sense.  You can't update in a SELECT.

Comment: Yes I am filtering on  9/2/2014, so I want to see only the pats with abc10. If I was filtering on 9/1/2014 I want to see only the pats with abc9.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questionable aspects to this code, such as using `between` with the same values, mixing left joins and inner joins, and doing a comparison in a `case` that is a no-op (due to the `where`).

However, the assignment in the `case` is definitely an error.  This is not allowed:

```
case when DATE > '9/1/2014' then abc.codetype = 'abc9' else abc.codetype = 'abc10' end
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
(case when [date] > '2014-09-01' then 'abc9' else 'abc10' end) as codetype
```